Primitive wine making
I'm very interested in primitive wine, so I have crushed the (red) grapes and put them in a drum. I have been told that for the first fermentation I should remove the lid and the after few days (5-7) days to filter the liquid and put it in another drum for the second fermentation. Is it right?
